# Are any Christians outside of the Catholic and Orthodox Churches *not* considered to be heretics by the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, heresy

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92708/are-nestorians-still-considered-heretics) regarding whether the Catholic Church considers the Assyrian Church of the East to be heretics made me wonder: are *any* Christians outside the Catholic and Orthodox churches *not* considered heretical by the Catholic Church?

Comment: Until recently [Catholics called Protestants heretics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heresy_in_the_Catholic_Church#Modern_Roman_Catholic_response_to_Protestantism), though now they often call them schismatics instead. Many Protestants have stricter criteria for heresy, namely rejecting the Nicene Creed as clarified by the Chalcedonian Definition. But other Protestants might call Catholics heretics as they teach a very different form of the Gospel.

Comment: @curiousdannii It's not on the question but on your remark: The Reformed Church does not support the Nicene Creed and Lutherans do not consider them heretics; Lutheran priests may work in a Reformed church and vice versa, at least in Switzerland and Germany.

Comment: @SDG Every Reformed church I know of supports the Nicene creed.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am member of the Reformed Church of Switzerland. We do not speak any creed and define ourselves as «bekenntnisfrei» which means «freedom in confession». This does not mean the complete lack of any personal confession but it is acceptable to have a different/differentiated opinion on the items in either version of the creed. It is also allowed to believe all of the Nicene Creed in either form, where of course, "Catholic Church" is understood as "Universal Church".