# Do Catholic anathemas apply to people who lived before it was codified?

Tags: catholicism, church-fathers, canon, canon-law, ecumenical-council

For example: Do the anathema issued by the Council of Trent regarding the canon of the scripture applies to the Church Fathers who believed in different canons in the early church before the Council of Trent happens?

> The sacred and holy, ecumenical, and general Synod of Trent,–lawfully
> assembled in the Holy Ghost, the Same three legates of the Apostolic
> Sec presiding therein,–keeping this [Page 18] always in view, that,
> errors being removed, the purity itself of the Gospel be preserved in
> the Church; which (Gospel), before promised through the prophets in
> the holy Scriptures, our Lord Jesus Christ, the Son of God, first
> promulgated with His own mouth, and then commanded to be preached by
> His Apostles to every creature, as the fountain of all, both saving
> truth, and moral discipline; and seeing clearly that this truth and
> discipline are contained in the written books, and the unwritten
> traditions which, received by the Apostles from the mouth of Christ
> himself, or from the Apostles themselves, the Holy Ghost dictating,
> have come down even unto us, transmitted as it were from hand to hand;
> (the Synod) following the examples of the orthodox Fathers, receives
> and venerates with an equal affection of piety, and reverence, all the
> books both of the Old and of the New Testament–seeing that one God is
> the author of both –as also the said traditions, as well those
> appertaining to faith as to morals, as having been dictated, either by
> Christ’s own word of mouth, or by the Holy Ghost, and preserved in the
> Catholic Church by a continuous succession. And it has thought it meet
> that a list of the sacred books be inserted in this decree, lest a
> doubt may arise in any one’s mind, which are the books that are
> received by this Synod. They are as set down here below: of the Old
> Testament: the five books of Moses, to wit, Genesis, Exodus,
> Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy; Josue, Judges, Ruth, four books of
> Kings, two of Paralipomenon, the first book of Esdras, and the second
> which is entitled Nehemias; Tobias, Judith, Esther, Job, the Davidical
> Psalter, consisting of a hundred and fifty psalms; the Proverbs,
> Ecclesiastes, the Canticle of Canticles, Wisdom, Ecclesiasticus,
> Isaias, Jeremias, with Baruch; Ezechiel, Daniel; the twelve minor
> prophets, to wit, Osee, Joel, Amos, Abdias, Jonas, Micheas, Nahum,
> Habacuc, Sophonias, Aggaeus, Zacharias, Malachias; two books of the
> Machabees, the first and the second. Of the New Testament: the four
> Gospels, according [Page 19] to Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John; the
> Acts of the Apostles written by Luke the Evangelist; fourteen epistles
> of Paul the apostle, (one) to the Romans, two to the Corinthians,
> (one) to the Galatians, to the Ephesians, to the Philippians, to the
> Colossians, two to the Thessalonians, two to Timothy, (one) to Titus,
> to Philemon, to the Hebrews; two of Peter the apostle, three of John
> the apostle, one of the apostle James, one of Jude the apostle, and
> the Apocalypse of John the apostle. But if any one receive not, as
> sacred and canonical, the said books entire with all their parts, as
> they have been used to be read in the Catholic Church, and as they are
> contained in the old Latin vulgate edition; and knowingly and
> deliberately contemn the traditions aforesaid; let him be anathema.
> Let all, therefore, understand, in what order, and in what manner, the
> said Synod, after having laid the foundation of the Confession of
> faith, will proceed, and what testimonies and authorities it will
> mainly use in confirming dogmas, and in restoring morals in the
> Church.
>
> -[Decree Concerning the Canonical Scriptures](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/councils/trent/fourth-session.htm)

Comment: No, because before a dogma is defined, it is only a [material (definable) dogma](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/68503/1787).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do Catholic [anathemas](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01455e.htm) apply to people who lived before it was codified?**

For example: *Do the anathemas issued by the Council of Trent regarding the canon of the scripture applies to the Church Fathers who believed in different canons in the early church before the Council of Trent happens?*

The simple answer is **no**.

An anathema or other penal law must exist at the time that an anathema was pronounced.

For example, in Canon Law, if a Law is changed it no longer exists, a penalty can not be applied. The principle logically would be appropriate both ways: past and future.

> [Can. 1313 §1.](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib6-cann1311-1363_en.html#TITLE_I_) If a law is changed after a delict has been committed, the law more favorable to the accused is to be applied.
>
> §2. If a later law abolishes a law or at least the penalty, the penalty immediately ceases.

The Church Fathers living in a time that a particular anathema did not exist, a future anathema can not be applied to them.

> Can. 1323 The following are not subject to a penalty when they have violated a law or precept:
>
> 1/ a person who has not yet completed the sixteenth year of age;
>
> 2/ **a person who without negligence was **ignorant** that he or she violated a law or precept; inadvertence and error are equivalent to ignorance.**

Thus if we follow the logic of Canon Law, such cases the Church could not anathematize someone.